# Freestyle stroke thickness change in different rendering resolutions

Tags: rendering, freestyle

Have I missed a checkbox somewhere? (Tried this question in other forums without response)
I’ve noticed that the stroke appearance alters when changing the render output resolution. This make the workflow a bit more cumbersome when testing stuff in the process. I’m looking for an option like “relative” or “absolute”: Doesn’t seem adding modifier “Distance from Camera” have any influence. Any Ideas?

Kindly, Raaskot

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Have you tried changing "Thickness Position" ?

Comment: No effect. Line Thickness Mode settings under Render tab was the correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interacting settings in different parts of the UI can make it easier to get a bit lost, here. This setting is in the **Render** tab, **Freestyle** Panel:

[image]

'Absolute' gives you a constant pixel-thickness. 'Relative' scales the base thickness by image-height, proportionately to 1px thickness at 480px image-height:

[image]

Above: Line thicknesses all at 1px. Images: 480x480, 960x960, 'Absolute', and 960x960, 'Relative'.